# Reload Mui Theme after fetch some service api

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

i need to update my global Mui Theme after a request. I have some custom colors storaged on my database so i need to load then into my client and create my Mui theme using those colors. My request is on a Route, and when it success I save the result on a context. I have tried to use the values of my request on my app.tsx, but I'd realized the app.tsx load before my request and never update anymore, because that I can't receive my values from my request and use it on Mui Theme.

That's a way to force Mui Theme to reload? Or force my App.tsx to reload after a request is done?

Thanks in advance

`theme.tsx`

```
const Theme: FC<IProps> = ({ children, program }) => {
  const theme = useMemo(
    () =>
      createTheme({
        palette: {
          primary: {
            main: program.primaryColor || primaryColor,
            light: shade(program.primaryColor || primaryColor, 0.5),
            dark: shade(program.primaryColor || primaryColor, -0.5),
            contrastText: shade(program.primaryColor || primaryColor, 1),
          },
          secondary: {
            main: program.secondaryColor || secondaryColor,
            light: shade(program.secondaryColor || secondaryColor, 0.5),
            dark: shade(program.secondaryColor || secondaryColor, -0.5),
            contrastText: shade(program.secondaryColor || secondaryColor, 1),
          },
          background: {
            paper: "#fff",
            default: "#e3e3e3",
          },
        },
        typography: {
          h1: {
            fontSize: "1.2rem",
            "@media (min-width:600px)": {
              fontSize: "1.4rem",
            },
            "@media (min-width:900px)": {
              fontSize: "2rem",
            },
            fontWeight: 600,
          },
          h2: {
            fontSize: "1.1rem",
            "@media (min-width:600px)": {
              fontSize: "1.2rem",
            },
            "@media (min-width:900px)": {
              fontSize: "1.8rem",
            },
            fontWeight: 500,
          },
        },
      }),
    [program.primaryColor]
  );

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={responsiveFontSizes(theme)}>
      <CssBaseline />
      {children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

`app.tsx`

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement
);

const App: FC = () => {
  const { program } = useProgramContext();

  return (
    <Theme program={program}>
      <SimpleBackdrop />
      <BrowserRouter>
        <AlertDialogSlide />
        <Router />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Theme>
  );
};

root.render(
  <Providers>
    <App />
  </Providers>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "client-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.8",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.17.23",
    "axios": "^1.3.2",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-query": "^3.39.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.9",
    "@types/node": "^18.13.0",
    "@types/react-color": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "eslint": "^8.22.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-with-typescript": "^22.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.2.5",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.1",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "prettier-eslint": "^15.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/jest": "^29.4.0"
  }
}
```

I tried to fetch the request before create the theme, but I can't doit, because I need a react-router param to fetch on backend.

Comment: Since the state of context has change, your App is rendered again and your Theme must apply the change with new value of program. Try change your useMemo dependencies to program instead of program.primaryColor

Comment: Thanks for asking Nghe Minh, I tried, but unfortunately my App is not render again